# What is the Spring Boot Webflux equivalent of the Morgan JS Library?

Tags: java, spring-boot, logging, kotlin

Javascript has an amazing library called [morgan](https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan) that logs out all the incoming http requests. Wondering if there's an equivalent library in Java/Kotlin for logging spring boot webflux requests.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what ended up working for me after having a look at this [repo](https://github.com/fbeaufume/webflux-filter-sample/blob/master/src/main/java/com/adeliosys/sample/LogFilter.java)

I have tried all night to get the request body as well, but kept getting errors re: single subscriber only per request. It's either impossible, pretty darn difficult, or not recommended in the case of requests with a large body (since it could block your server). So I would highly recommend you convert your `@RequestBody` objects to `@RequestParam` query params instead if you want to log variables in post requests.

```
package com.example.demo

import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component
import org.springframework.web.server.ServerWebExchange
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilter
import org.springframework.web.server.WebFilterChain
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono


@Component
class LogFilter: WebFilter {

    private val logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LogFilter::class.java)

    override fun filter(exchange: ServerWebExchange, chain: WebFilterChain): Mono<Void> {
        val startTime = System.currentTimeMillis()
        val request = exchange.request
        val path = request.uri.path

        val requestPrintMap = mutableMapOf<Any, Any>()
        requestPrintMap["headers"] = request.headers
        requestPrintMap["uri"] = request.uri
        requestPrintMap["params"] = request.queryParams

        return chain
                .filter(exchange)
                .doAfterTerminate {

            logger.info("Served '{}' as {} in {} msec",
                    path,
                    exchange.response.statusCode,
                    System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime)
        }
    }

}
```